# Axios request closing with socket hang up

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

Hi I am using a mac and I am trying to do a request with axios. Regardless if its an post request or a get request or even url ( I have tried multiple like google.com and etc.) I still keep getting `socket hang up ECONNRESET`
Here's a simple request I do:

```
let config = {
      method: "get",
      url: "https://google.com"
    };

    try {
      const response = await axios(config);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    }
    catch(err){
      console.log(err.message, err.code)
    }
    res.send({JSON.stringify(response)});
```

The response always is `socket hang up ECONNRESET`.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What output do you get when you do `$nslookup google.com` in your terminal?

Comment: I checked the response is coming fine on postman as well but here's the output:

Server:  156.36.192.23
Address: 156.36.192.23#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: google.com
Address: 142.250.190.46